# Access contents of a text file in the client machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, client, text-files

In our web application we want to get some data from a text file saved in a client machine. The text file is saved in a particular location in the client machine.

We want to get the contents of that text file from our application. Is there any method to read the contents of a text file in client machine.

Thanks,

mahesh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is not.  You will need to get your client to choose to upload this file for you.

If you think about it, it would be a massive security hole if you could do this.

Comment: @Paddy: yes, can we do this like a file upload control, in file upload control, the client selects the file to be uploaded, but here we know the exact physical path in the client machine and we want to get that file like the client uploading the file.

Comment: The client will still have to initiate this upload - I don't think that there is a way to programatically set the file path into this control.